# Azure web app connection string in configuration fetch values from KeyVault

Tags: security, azure-web-app-service, connection-string, azure-keyvault, azure-webapps

I need to configure passwords to be fetched from Azure KeyVault in Azure Web App connection string. Can someone explain how to configure it ?

[image]

Thanks in advance !

I tried to get the passwords from key vault in Application settings and it worked fine , but couldn't able to integrate it in connection string.

Comment: Refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli), you can use `key vault` references.

Comment: What is the `version` and `framwork` of the Web App you are using?

Comment: It is a `Core` or `.Net framework` Web App ?

Answer (score 0):

- Create an `Azure KeyVault`.
- Create Secret. Copy the `Secret Identifier` of the Secret (this has to be used in Azure Configuration `Connection String`).

[image]

- Provide necessary grants by using `Access policies`.
- In `Azure App Service` => `Configuration` => `Application Settings` => `Connection Strings`, add the new Connection string setting.
- For .NET Core App, the key name has to be `MyNewConn`.
- For .NET Framework App, the name in the `Azure App Connection String` must be same as the key name in `Local Configuration`.

Thanks @Anand Sowmithiran for the Comment.

- The value of the Connection string has to be `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=Secret Identifier)`.
- Replace the `Secret Identifier` value with the value which we have copied from the `KeyVault` Secret (In Step 1).

[image]

***For `.NET Core` Web App***

`appsettings.json`

```cs
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyNewConn": "LocalValue"
  }
```

```cs
string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("MyNewConn");
```

***For `.NET Framework` Web App***

- In `Web.config` file, you must have the below settings

```cs
 <configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*****" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
      <add name="AzureKeyVault" vaultName="KeyVaultName" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"  vaultUri="https://YourKeyVaultName.vault.azure.net" />
    </builders>
  </configBuilders>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyNewConn" connectionString="Retrieves the value from Azure App Service Connection String" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

```cs
 var conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyNewConn"];
```

### Update

- In `Azure Key Vault`,  the step where we create the Secret, add the Secret value as the connection string.
  [image].

Rest other steps are same.

Comment: Thank you @Harshitha, I already tried this way , Can you please share how use Application setting values in connection string ?

Comment: Its a Dotnetcore - 5.0 Web Application

Comment: Please share your `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: Please find the appsettings configuration for reference


  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=tcp:sqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Database;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30"
  },

Comment: Please let me know what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Harshitha, My goal is to use passwords in the connection string  to be fetched from Key Vault , as its been visible as a plain text from azure portal (Image provided in the question). However I can able to fetch passwords from key vault separately in Application setting , but couldn't able to integrate the Application setting variable value in connection string from azure portal.

Comment: @jegadishkumar - Please check the update in the answer.